# VMWare player - how do I start VM on machine with lower RAM?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player

I moved image from one machine to another. Problem is - I didn't shut down' instance, just suspended it.

On machine #1 I have 32G and instance had 16Gb allocated. On machine #2 I have only 10G and instance won't resume (due to memory)

But I can't lower amount of memory - I guess because machine in "suspended".

Anyway to lower memory or "shut down" instance without powering? How do I start it on machine #2?

Comment: VMWare Player is not designed for these sorts work. That's why they have VMWare Workstation (at a cost), which specifically has an option to discard the saved state. Otherwise my guess is you're down to manually deleting files. Additionaly, vmware player is not licensed for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

You add more memory.

You won't be able to do what you want, particularly just with VMWare player.  If you must avoid shutting down this VM, you'll have to transfer it back to the machine with enough RAM to accommodate it.  Or, if you don't have to keep it up, you could power down the VM and then modify the amount of memory the VM has.